# WCF service maxConcurrentSessions

Tags: wcf

I created a WCF service and the user requirement is to have only one client connected on the service at a time.

So I set the value of the parameter maxConcurrentSessions to 1.

It's working great and if another client try to connect after a specific time it receives a timeout exception error.

But I don't like to send the timeout exception error to the client I want to have a more specific error like :

A timeout occurs because the number of maximum client on the service was reached.

Something like that.

It's there a way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: wrap it with another WCF service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override default exceptions by implementing IErrorHandler

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx)

> To explicitly **control the behavior of the application when an
>   exception is thrown, implement the IErrorHandler interface** and add it
>   to the ErrorHandlers property. IErrorHandler enables you to explicitly
>   control the SOAP fault generated, decide whether to send it back to
>   the client, and perform associated tasks, such as logging. Error
>   handlers are called in the order in which they were added to the
>   ErrorHandlers property.
>
> **Implement the ProvideFault method to control the fault message that is
>   returned to the client**

Also check this one [.Net WFC/Web service exception handling design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445093/net-wfc-web-service-exception-handling-design-pattern)

Comment: Yes but my goal is like to know if this timeout occured because the maxconcurrent sessions is reached.  I mean, client A connect to the service, client B connect but enter a queue because a client is already connected to the service.  A timeout occurs for client B after X times because it wasn't able to do the connection.  How I can know the timeout occurs because a max session was reached.  It's there's a way to know if the maxconcurrentsession is reached in WCF ?

Comment: Looks like you are changing your goals :), Your original goal was to send a specific message , To achieve your new goal one approach could be write your custom binding and use maxoutboundconnectionsperendpoint http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.tcpconnectionpoolsettingselement.maxoutboundconnectionsperendpoint.aspx